# how to remove inputMismatchException while reading a .txt file using scanner in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FrequencyCount
{
    public static void main(String...args) throws IOException
    {
        int count0=0;
        int count1=0;
        int x=0;
        //System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("F:\\DUCAT COCHNG\\java progs\\IO\\str.txt.txt"));
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            x=scan.nextInt();
            if(x==0)
                count0++;
            else if(x==1)
                count1++;
        }   

        System.out.println("Frequency of 0's is: "+count0);
        System.out.println("Frequency of 1's is: "+count1);

    }
}
```

output shown is:

> F:\DUCAT COCHNG\java progs\IO>java FrequencyCount Exception in thread
>   "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "
>   00000111010010011001010010100101010001000101110111110101010011101001001010010010
>   1"
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2165)
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2118)
>           at FrequencyCount.main(FrequencyCount.java:15)
>
> F:\DUCAT COCHNG\java progs\IO>

str.txt file is:

> 000001110100100110010100101001010100010001011101111101010100111010010010100100101

Comment: `1110100100110010100101001010100010001011101111101010100111010010010100100101` is not an `int`, nor can it fit in a `long`. You might be in need to read the whole line as a `String` and store it in a `BigInteger` here. A

Comment: Read one character at a time, makes more sense since you are just counting frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help:

```
try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
           String str = scan.next(); 
            char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();
            for(char c: myChar){
                x=Character.getNumericValue(c);
                if(x==0) 
                    count0++; 
                else if(x==1) 
                    count1++; 
            }
        }
       System.out.println("Frequency of 0's is: "+count0);
       System.out.println("Frequency of 1's is: "+count1);
   }
  catch(Exception e)
  { e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `scan.hasNextInt()` instead of `scan.hasNext()`.  The latter checks for any token, and I suspect you have a new line at the end of your file that scanner is parsing.  This obviously can't be converted to an integer, and so the exception is thrown.

You may also want to close your `scanner` as well.  Just use `scan.close()`.  Not strictly necessary here in such a small program, but good practice.